# Can we handle all the errors scenarios of http (4XX-5XX) using catch(error) in JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, catch-block

I am using a promise to access some data from some URL and to catch the errors i want to use .catch .
If i miss some error i can anyway catch in .finally but what all errors am i ignoring?

```
 $http.get('/someUrl', config)
      .then(function(data) {      
    }).catch(function activateError(error) {
           if (!error.handled) {
           alert(error);
           }
    }).finally(function(){
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The response of the $http call returns an object with a `status` property.
It's a number corresponding to the response code of your request.

So you could try handling your errors this way:

```
$http.get(dataUrl)
    .success(function (data){
    })
    .error(function (error, status){
       if (!error.handled) {
           alert(error);
       }
       // handle error treatment with status code
  });
```

Hope it helped!